# Apply anchor for Winform Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, anchor, controls, dock

In my **Winform** application, Contains a Two Panels, One is Above and another one is Below(like One by one).

Both Panels contains DataGridView. DataGridview is docked(Fill) in the Panels.

So when I run my application , I need to expand or compress my form..

at the time both the panels needs to be expand as well as compress.

[My Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsQy4.jpg)

If gave anchor(Bottom, Left, Right) for both panels, Then expanding form, it will be like this
[First Modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOzlt.jpg)

If gave anchor(Top, Left, Right) for first panel and anchor(), Then expanding form, it will be like this(i can't able to post more than 2 links)

I tried:

> Panel1 => Top,Right,Left
>    Panel2 => Bottom ,Right,Left

or

> Panel1 => Right,Left
>   Panel2=> Right,Left

or

> etc..

I tried like this. Once I change anything it will overlap others.... but ... .

The problem is, Panels are responsible, when i expanding form and compressing form. But the alignment will changes every time. I want to make the panels gets bigger when expanding and get smaller when compressing the form. Don't overlaps one to another. It simply expand and compress.

how to I do that. Helps appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a **SplitContainer**, it's used exactly for what you are describing.